# Get all matches in a preg_match request

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm having the following problem, i have that structure:

```
$table = '
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td>foo</td>
            <td>bar</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td>bee</td>
            <td>dog</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>';
```

I'm trying to retrieve an array with all `<tr>` but with no success. The closest pattern I've could made it, return all messed up.

```
$pattern = "/<tr valign[^>]*>(.*)<\/tr>/s";
preg_match_all($pattern, $table, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

If i put `var_dump($matches)`, I want an array that returns:

```
array(
    [0] => "<td>foo</td><td>bar</td>",
    [1] => "<td>bee</td><td>dog</td>"
);
```

...or something close to that.

But I receive:

```
string(301) "
    foo
    bar
    "
<table>
        <tbody>
            <tr valign="top">
                <td>bee</td>
                <td>dog</td>
            </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `simplexml` or `domdocument` not regex.

Comment: As for the regex question: your match is [too greedy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must make your quantifier lazy: `.*` => `.*?`

When you use a greedy quantifier, `.*` will take all possible characters, When you use a lazy quantifier, `.*?` will take the minimum number of characters.

When you use a lazy quantifier, the regex engine will take characters one by one and test the pattern completion for each character.

When you use a greedy quantifier (default behavior) the regex engine will take all possible characters (until the end in your case) and will backtrack character by character until the pattern completion succeed.

Notes:

It is useless to add `PREG_PATTERN_ORDER` since it is the default set of `preg_match_all`.

DOMDocument is probably a more adapted tool to deal with html. Example:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($table);

$trs = $dom->getElementsByTagName('tr');

$results = array();

foreach ($trs as $tr) {
    if ($tr->hasAttribute('valign')) {
        $children = $tr->childNodes;

        $tmp = '';
        foreach ($children as $child) {
            $tmp .= trim($dom->saveHTML($child));
        }
        if (!empty($tmp)) $results[] = $tmp;
    }
}

echo htmlspecialchars(print_r($results, true));
```